# Finding all the solutions to a complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I am asked to find all the solutions to $z^{42}=-1$. I go a head and square root both sides to produce $z^{21}= i$. Then I can write $z^{21}= r^{21} (\cos(21\ θ) + i\sin(21\ θ)) = 0+i. $ Hence $\cos(21\ θ)= 0$ and $\sin(21\ θ)=1$, as $r^{21} $ can't be equal to $0$. Therefore $21θ $ = ${π \over 2} $ and $ θ = {π\over42}$. Then using $\sin(21\ θ)=1$,  I can write  $r^{21}=1 $ and produce that $r\pm1$ $\ $so my answer would be $z=\pm \cos({π\over42}) + i\sin({π\over42}). $

My answer doesn't produce the cleanest numbers so I'm a little worried but I do believe the process is correct.

Comment: This equation has 42 solutions.

Comment: Try expressing the solutions in polar coordinates.

Comment: hehe Thanks, worked from a too basic example question.

Comment: "I go ahead and square root both sides to produce $z^{21} = i$" - don't do this!

Comment: If $z^{42}=-1$ then $z^{21}=\pm i$

Answer (score 2):

You could just come to my consulting hour tomorrow :-)  Hint: no need to square root. We did an example like this in class.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: where $n$ is an integer,
$$z^{42}=-1$$$$(re^{i\theta})^{42}=1e^{i \pi }$$
$$r^{42}e^{i 42\theta}=1e^{i(\pi+ 2 \pi n)}$$

Note $r\ge 0$ (by definition), and that $e^{i2\pi n}=1$.